# Adopt this poor orphan repo, or, giving my branch a missing parent

Tags: git, github

I have a local, private repo that I created by cloning origin/master, and making some changes to local files, mostly adds. When I cloned, the repo was created without a parent. I committed to the repo, and discovered my mistake when I tried to push: no mommy branch, no pushie branch.

I would be happy if I could 'adopt' the origin/master as of right now (better yet, a few days back), just as if I did it right in the first place. Is this the git-fu I need?

git push --set-upstream origin personal/my_identity/tests

Should I be using 'origin' literally or do I need a branch name in there? Can I specify a branch at a particular point in the past? Or is this a job for 'rebase'?